# How to enumerate adjectives without using the same noun? How to give preference to the noun?

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives

> I like orange, chocolate, strawberry & banana, kiwi, pineapple and vanilla
>   **milkshakes**.

Imagining there are many more adjectives, in case someone wants to emphasize and give preference to the noun "milkshakes", is there any possibility to correctly say: **"I like milkshakes of..."** or something similar?

What about the next example? How would you phrase it?:

> I like orange milkshakes as well as chocolate and kiwi *ones(?)*

Comment: I love milkshakes; especially orange, chocolate, strawberry & banana, kiwi, pineapple and vanilla flavours!

Answer (score 2):

> "I like milkshakes with kiwi, chocolate, or orange in them."

You can change the adjectives into nouns if the object allows it.

> "Orange, chocolate, or kiwi milkshakes are my preference."

You can change the subject to convey the same meaning. I (subject) like (verb) noun list(object) vs (adjective list) milkshakes(object) are my preference(subject).